# ASP.Net: Can I capture a users network username from an internet website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication

We have a windows domain and we are starting to deploy applications onto external servers outside of the network, to simplify authentication we would like to capture the users network username to achieve authentication.

Is there any way of capturing this from an ASP.Net website hosted outside of our network?  If so, is this straightforward?

Comment: You want to connect to active directory that resides on a different domain? I'm pretty sure that wont be possible. Good luck with that, interested to see if you get a resolution that!

Comment: When you host outside the domain its not windows authentication and you may not get the Identity preserves the domain and user name

Comment: @Derek I don't really need to connect to AD, I just need the username that the user is logged in as, and then authenticate the user against a database table.

Comment: @Murali that's what I thought might be the case, which is why I'm asking to see if there is a way to achieve it, obviously the website is going to want credentials to it's own domain, and what I need to do is pass them from the users current domain, tricky.